# Unit testing BizTalk pipeline with dependency to context property

Tags: unit-testing, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to build unit tests for a BizTalk pipeline using the TestableReceivePipeline. I have followed the steps described here:
[Using the Unit Testing Feature with Pipelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd792682.aspx)

The pipeline I am trying to test has a pipeline component that reads the ReceivedFileName context property.

Since the message don't go through the FILE adapter in the tests, the context property does not exist and the test fails.

Is there any way I can inject context properties in the test i.e. set the ReceivedFileName property in the unit test?

Answer (score 0):

In the custom pipeline write the following code:

```
// This will be the name of file.
string filename = "NameOfFile";

// myMsg is the IBaseMessage which will be the output.
myMsg.Context.Write("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties", filename);
myMsg.Context.Promote("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties", filename);
```

Now you can follow your usual steps as "ReceivedFileName" is promoted.